# how to refresh the page after jquery call

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

I am trying to take the user to login page after cookies are cleared.
I am making a jquery call to my controller to clean the cookies but then I don't know how to redirect him to login page.

I am currently have this code inside my javascript:

```
    function()
    {
    $.post('/Home/Action', function(result) {

                                    });
              window.location="login";
      }
public Action()
{
    cookie cleaning code;
}
```

but the problem is refreshing and cookie cleaning are done at the same time. I want to take the user after cookie cleaning.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why did you put `window.location` outside `$.post` callback? Try this:

```
function() {
    $.post('/Home/Action', function(result) {
        window.location.href = "login";
    });

}
```

Comment: I tried that before but for some reason I missed or done something and it didn't work. But it did now.

Answer (score 1):

```
function CleanCookiesAndGotoLogin()
{
    $.post('/Home/Action', function(result) {
         //you put the relocation here so that it waits for the callback
        window.location="/ControllerName/ActionName";
    });
};
```